# Defining multiple logical OR constraints in PuLP MIP

Tags: python, linear-programming, pulp, mixed-integer-programming

Say, I have a set of binary variables like so:

```
ht = {}
for t in range(100):
    ht[t] = pulp.LpVariable('ht[%i]' % t, lowBound=0, upBound=1, cat='Integer')
```

I want to make sure that there is a gap between ht[t], such that:

```
ht[t] + ht[t + 1] + ht[t + 2] + ht[t + 3] + ht[t + 4] + ht[t + 5] <= 1
OR
ht[t - 1] + ht[t] + ht[t + 1] + ht[t + 2] + ht[t + 3] + ht[t + 4] <= 1
OR
ht[t - 2] + ht[t - 1] + ht[t] + ht[t + 1] + ht[t + 2] + ht[t + 3] <= 1
OR
ht[t - 3] + ht[t - 2] + ht[t - 1] + ht[t] + ht[t + 1] + ht[t + 2] <= 1
OR
ht[t - 4] + ht[t - 3] + ht[t - 2] + ht[t - 1] + ht[t] + ht[t + 1] <= 1
OR
ht[t - 5] + ht[t - 4] + ht[t - 3] + ht[t - 2] + ht[t - 1] + ht[t] <= 1
```

Depending on the position of 't', adjacent neighbors to the left and/or right need to be 0.

Is it possible to write this constraint in PuLP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, this is not so easy or cheap: we need extra binary variables for that:

```
ht[t] + ht[t + 1] + ht[t + 2] + ht[t + 3] + ht[t + 4] + ht[t + 5] <= 1 + 5 * δ[t,1]
ht[t - 1] + ht[t] + ht[t + 1] + ht[t + 2] + ht[t + 3] + ht[t + 4] <= 1 + 5 * δ[t,2]
ht[t - 2] + ht[t - 1] + ht[t] + ht[t + 1] + ht[t + 2] + ht[t + 3] <= 1 + 5 * δ[t,3]
ht[t - 3] + ht[t - 2] + ht[t - 1] + ht[t] + ht[t + 1] + ht[t + 2] <= 1 + 5 * δ[t,4]
ht[t - 4] + ht[t - 3] + ht[t - 2] + ht[t - 1] + ht[t] + ht[t + 1] <= 1 + 5 * δ[t,5]
ht[t - 5] + ht[t - 4] + ht[t - 3] + ht[t - 2] + ht[t - 1] + ht[t] <= 1 + 5 * δ[t,6]
δ[t,1]+δ[t,2]+δ[t,3]+δ[t,4]+δ[t,5]+δ[t,6] <= 5
δ[t,k] ∈ {0,1}
```

The terms `5 * δ[t,k]` in the constraints mean:

```
δ[t,k]=0 => k-th constraint is active
δ[t,k]=1 => k-th constraint is relaxed
```

We need at least one active constraint hence we don't allow all `δ[t,k]` to be 1.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thank you!  This kind of works, but for some reason I'm getting a gap of 3-4 '0' cells rather than the expected 5. Maybe I'm defining the constraints wrong?

Comment: Try `and` instead of `or`. For `and` you don't need any tricks. Looks like you posed the wrong question.

Comment: Yes, that worked. Sorry for the confusion, I thought it was more complicated than it was.